# Centering elements within their allocated space in the align(ed) environment

Tags: align

In the following MWE I've tried to use `align` to ensure similarly colored terms are located one atop the other. I'm looking for a solution which:

1. Centers colored terms around a joint vertical axis, itself centered with respect to the allocated horizontal space.
2. Have the whole aligned environment take up only as much horizontal space as needed (as in example 2)
3. Give each equation its own tag/label (as in example 1)
4. These serve as one example of many, I'd like to avoid having to manualy
   specify an alignment of "this part from this to that part from that" beyond what `align` already knows.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\newcommand{\COne}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\CTwo}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
( \varphi \rightarrow (&{\COne\psi} &\rightarrow {\CTwo\chi} ) )   \\
( \varphi \rightarrow ( &{\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )} &\rightarrow{\CTwo\varphi} ) )
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
( \varphi \rightarrow (&{\COne\psi} &&\rightarrow {\CTwo\chi} ) )   \\
( \varphi \rightarrow ( &{\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )} &&\rightarrow{\CTwo\varphi} ) )
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: My efforts so far]

Here's roughly the result I'm after:

[image]

**Update**:
@Werner's solution works great, except for larger expressions, I'm still getting unintended "stretching" in the output:

```
\begin{align}
( \varphi \rightarrow (&\eqmakebox[a]{$\COne\psi$} \rightarrow {\CTwo\chi} )  \rightarrow 
 ( ( \varphi \rightarrow &\eqmakebox[b]{$\COne\psi$} ) \rightarrow ( \varphi \rightarrow{\CTwo \chi} ) )  \\
( \varphi \rightarrow ( &\eqmakebox[a]{$\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )$} \rightarrow  {\CTwo\varphi} ) ) \rightarrow  
( ( \varphi \rightarrow &\eqmakebox[b]{$\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi ) $}) \rightarrow ( \varphi \rightarrow {\CTwo\varphi} ) )
\end{align}
```

**Final result**: Thank you @Werner.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xcolor} 
\newcommand{\COne}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\CTwo}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{5}
\varphi \rightarrow (&\eqmakebox[a]{$\COne\psi$} &\rightarrow &{\CTwo\chi} ) &\rightarrow 
( ( \varphi \rightarrow &\eqmakebox[b]{$\COne\psi$} ) \rightarrow ( \varphi \rightarrow{\CTwo \chi} )  \\
\varphi \rightarrow ( &\eqmakebox[a]{$\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )$} &\rightarrow  &{\CTwo\varphi} ) ) &\rightarrow  
( ( \varphi \rightarrow &\eqmakebox[b]{$\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi ) $}) \rightarrow ( \varphi \rightarrow {\CTwo\varphi} ) 
\end{alignat}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set like-width items in a box of similar width using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`. Similar `<tag>`s will yield similar-sized boxes (width-wise, matching the widest `<stuff>`), where you can change the `<align>`ment as well (default is `c`entre):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,eqparbox}
\newcommand{\COne}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\CTwo}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  ( \varphi \rightarrow ( &{\COne\psi} &\rightarrow {\CTwo\chi} ) )   \\
  ( \varphi \rightarrow ( &{\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )} &\rightarrow{\CTwo\varphi} ) )
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  ( \varphi \rightarrow ( &{\COne\psi} &&\rightarrow {\CTwo\chi} ) )   \\
  ( \varphi \rightarrow ( &{\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )} &&\rightarrow{\CTwo\varphi} ) )
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  ( \varphi \rightarrow ( &\eqmakebox[psi]{$\COne\psi$} \rightarrow {\CTwo\chi} ) )   \\
  ( \varphi \rightarrow ( &\eqmakebox[psi]{$\COne( \varphi \rightarrow \varphi )$}\rightarrow{\CTwo\varphi} ) )
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Compile twice at the first go, since the widest element width is written to the `.aux` and read in during a subsequent run. Any changes to elements within the widest `<stuff>` will require additional runs.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm still experiencing unexplained stretching with larger expressions, I've added an example to the question. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @KenGold: `align` inserts a large space between equations (horizontally) if you use more than one `&`. If you want to avoid this, rather use `\begin{alignat}{2}` ([output using `alignat`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytgIU.png)). Of course, you can also place multiple `\eqmakebox`es... however many as you want, each with a different key make things align your way.